# How I can send message to the timeline of gamer friends

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for a way to send messages for friends timeline of players by JS. I found 2 ways:

- by FB.api('/FRIEND_ID/feed', ...), but this feature will be removed
  soon, so I decided not to use it.
- and by FB.ui('apprequest', ...), but this way dont send message to
  timeline but only notify in the App Center.

I tried to send links for friends, but not all can receive links of my app.
I need another way to do it. Some people have another idea to send message in the timeline for 1 or more people without confirmation (or many confirmations)?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of spammy stuff is the reason Facebook removed the ability to post to friends using the graph api. You can now only present the feed dialog, but it is up to the user to complete the post.